# Exponential inequalities to quadratic inequalities

Tags: inequality

I'm having a problem.
To be more clear!

$$9^x-3^x-6 <0$$

$$3^x=t$$

$$t^2-t-6 <0$$

$$t=-2$$

$$t=3$$

$$t \in (2,3)$$
What to do now? How to find $x$?

Comment: Is it $9^x-3^x-6<0$ ? or $9^x-3^{x-6}<0$

Comment: Which, if any, of these statements do you want to be true?  $t^2 - t - 6 = (t+2)(t-3) < 0$ if and only if $-2 < t < 3$.  $9^x - 3^x - 6 = t^2 - t - 6$ if $t = 3^x$.

Comment: I don't understand that substitution $x^2=t$, shouldn't it be $3^x=t$ ?

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Please $t^2-t-6=(t+2)(t-3)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put $3^x=t$.

Then you will have $(t+2)(t-3)<0 \Rightarrow -2<t<3 $

But $3^x>0 $ for all $x\in \mathbb{R} \Rightarrow 0<t<3$.

Therefore $x\in(-\infty,1)$

Answer (score 1):

You now know that the original inequality holds if and only if $2<3^x<3$.

The next step is to solve this pair inequalities, i.e. find out when $3^x<3$ and when $3^x>2.$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: you will get $-2<3^x<3$